# How to mock HashMap with MockK using kotlin and junit?

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockk

I need generate a hashmap with follows values using MockK.

Ex.:

```
Map mapa = HashMap()
mapa.put("Authorization","blabla")
```

I need using mockK.

Something like that:

```
val meuMock = mockk<<HashMap<String,String>>{
every{...} returns ...
}
```

I don't know how it works and I didn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to return `blabla` for each invocation of `map["Authorization"]`.

So in that case you have to mock the behavior of method get for key `"Authorization"`.

Solution:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `test`() {
        val map = mockk<HashMap<String, String>>()

        every { map["Authorization"] } returns "blabla"

        assertEquals("blabla", map.get("Authorization"))
    }
```